# OutOfMemoryException when trying to download big file

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
byte[] fileBytes = null;

using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
  fileBytes = wc.DownloadData(filename);
}
```

filename is an url that contains something like "file://example.com/Media-Data/thisisabigmovie.wmv"

Now my customer seems to have really big files which throw the following error:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: 
   at System.Net.ScatterGatherBuffers.AllocateMemoryChunk(Int32 newSize)
   at System.Net.ScatterGatherBuffers.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.RetrieveBytes(Int32& bytesRetrieved)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)
```

Is there a way to solve this? Maybe download the file in "chunks"?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163451/system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown-webclient-downloadstringasynch

Comment: There's certainly a stream based variant or one that let's you specify a target file.

Comment: Use `wc.OpenRead` method to stream the file instead of reading on shot. Alternatively you can use `wc.OpenReadAsync` and `wc.OpenWriteCompleted` methods to read asynchronously.

Comment: use more than 2GB of RAM.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you planning to do with the file once downloaded? If you're immediately going to save it to disk, you can simply use WebClient's `DownloadFile` method instead of `DownloadData`. `DownloadFile` uses `FileStream` internally and saves to disk in chunks, as you guessed:

```
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
   wc.DownloadFile(remoteUri, localFilename);
}
```

If you need to process the bytes and not just save them, you should use a Stream-based approach to get the data as a stream - meaning you process it as it arrives, not after you've stored it all in memory. For this, `WebClient` won't help you, and you should use the newer `HttpClient` or the older, more low-level `HttpWebRequest`

```
var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(remoteUrl);
var dataStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

or

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteUrl);
var response = request.GetResponse();
var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `DownloadData` because that returns the response in a `Byte[]` which will hit .NET's 2GB maximum object size limit.

You should use `HttpClient` or raw `HttpWebRequest` objects instead of `WebClient` and pipe the response streams directly to a `FileStream` on disk or so. Use the `CopyToAsync` method for this:

```
using( Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream() )
using( FileStream fileStream = new FileStream( "tempFile.bin" ) )
{
    await responseStream.CopyToAsync( fileStream ).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Why he cannot use `WebClient`? It can do the same. You can get stream with `OpenRead` or you can just download straight to the file with `DownloadFile`.

Comment: If, big IF, the user is running on 64bit and has some Ram, you can use more than 2GB by setting the following flag: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element

Comment: @screig The maximum index on an array is still `UInt32.MaxValue` so with a `Byte[]` the maximum capacity is 4GiB - not much of an improvement.

Comment: The trouble with WebClient is that you cant use Cookies (or a proxy if that is important)