# System.outofmemory exception while downloading large size zip

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am downloading a large size zip file with multiple images. its working fine till 200mb but after this its giving me System.outofmemory exception. I want to download a large size zip approx(700 - 800mb). Is there any way to overcome System.outofmemory exception and download large size zip file?

Comment: Please show the code you're using - we're not going to be able to help you without that. Also, please clarify whether it's the server that's *serving* the zip file that's crashing, or the client.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OutOfMemoryException when trying to download big file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106596/outofmemoryexception-when-trying-to-download-big-file)

Comment: I'm using the following code and i got Outofmemoryexception near zip.save().var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
List<string> files = objOrder.GetFileName(photoIds).ToList();
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
  zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;
  zip.AddDirectoryByName(zipName.Trim());
  for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
  {
    string filePath= files[i];    
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
      zip.AddEntry(zipName.Trim(), wc.DownloadData(filePath));
    }
  }
  zip.Save(outputStream);
}
outputStream.Position = 0;

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are downloading the zip file, but use something like this:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    // fileUri = URI of the file you are downloading
    // filename = Target filepath to write the file
    client.DownloadFile(fileUri, filename);
}
```

Using `WebClient.DownloadFile()` will cause the file to be downloaded and persisted on disk in pieces rather than a whole, in-memory object.  This will overcome the issue with running out of memory.

`WebClient` is located in `System.Net`.

If you subsequently want to unzip the file, you can run the operation against your on-disk file rather than a `MemoryStream` or `byte` array.

Comment: I also using WebClient.DownloadFile() but its working fine. I got exception near zip.save().

Comment: @AjayRathore So the error is nothing to do with downloading the file at all?  It's to do with when you unzip it?

Comment: Yes, its giving error when i download zip file or creating zip